# How do a make a countdown timer reset or go back up by a few seconds?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make this time go up in time by say 5 seconds or to reset when I enter a trigger.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Timer2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float timeLeft = 3.0f;
    public Text startText; // used for showing countdown from 3, 2, 1 


    void Update()
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        startText.text = (timeLeft).ToString("0");
        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            if (timeLeft < 0)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried simply adding to the `timeLeft` variable?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Timer2 : MonoBehaviour
{

public float timeLeft = 3.0f;
public Text startText; // used for showing countdown from 3, 2, 1 


void Update()
{
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    startText.text = (timeLeft).ToString("0");
    if (timeLeft < 0)
    {
        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    //check to see if the collision is correct
    timeLeft += 5; //parameterize this number if needed
}
}
```

if you want to reset the `timeLeft` instead, just replace  `timeLeft += 5;` with `timeLeft = 3.0f` (you probably want to move the initial value to a variable if you are to do this)